# AppxManifest file not being generated correctly

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I've been using the Visual Studio 2015 tools to create an Apache Cordova project. However, on attempting to upload my app package to the Windows Dev Center, I get this error:

> 3201: The publisher display name, $username$, specified in the package
>   doesn’t match the publisher name, Ciaran, that’s associated with the
>   developer account.

Upon examination of the source .appxmanifest file that gets generated automatically when building my application, I've found that it gets generated with placeholder variables like $username$ in place of my actual username. I've already used the 'Associate App with the Store' option and it reports success, although this doesn't seem to have any effect on the generated appxmanifest files, nor when building the application nor when creating the app package file.

I already tried contact Microsoft Support about this issue, but so far they are just linking to me documentation on the App Manifest file, which doesn't seem useful to me because the Apache Cordova project doesn't seem to give me any control over the App Manifest file. If I try to change it manually, it just gets overwritten again when the application is built.

I've tried re-creating the project and I've tried cancelling and deleting the app submission from the Windows Dev servers and trying everything all over again, but I still run into this same issue.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I contacted Microsoft support on this issue, however I was told that the support team do not provide support for Apache Cordova projects. Additionally, I was told that submitting apps from the beta version of Visual Studio 2015 is not permitted, that submissions are only possible through the retail version of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Hi Ciaran,  Although you cannot phone in for support until the product hits RTM we will be watching the StackOverflow tag visual-studio-cordova.  You should be able to submit app packages created with Visual Studio 2015.  I am not aware of anything in the current version that would be an issue!

Comment: How are you getting this appxmanifest file to generate? I'm able to build and deploy a test version of a cordova app to a nokia lumia in VS2015 but see no appxmanifest file and obviously have issues trying to associate app or create app package when right clicking on the project.

Comment: @JeffSanders-MSFT I have been trying to make an Apache Cordova app for WP8.1 and am running VS2015 Community Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL and the whole Store section underneath "Project" is completely grayed out for me and I am at a total dead end with the project right now. Is there an issue with this version of VS2015? I'm seeing so much conflicting or spotty information on SO and online that I absolutely have no clue what to think. Making this Cordova app for Android and iOS was a breeze compared to this. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can use native project to create appx package.

Steps to create appx package using windows native project:

1. Native project is located under bld\Debug\platforms\windows and it is created as a part of build process.
2. Open CordovaApp.sln
3. Open Create App Package wizard and follow the wizard to create appx package

[image]

4. Grab the package from output location displayed on Package Creation Completed page.
   [image]

Comment: That worked flawlessly, thanks for the comprehensive instructions, it's been a great help! I was able to publish the app with no issue with this method.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the most recent public releases of VS Cordova tools - VS 2015 CTP6 and CTP3.1 for VS 2013 Update 4.

Comment: Not trying to necro this thread @Abishek but can you explain how to do this in Visual Studio 2015? In Project -> Store the entire dropdown is greyed out and I cannot select anything.