# Error:3201 during Cordova App deployment on Windows

Tags: correlation, windows, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to create package of cordova application.
App Passes the local validations but gives following error on file uploading:

```
3201: The publisher display name, $username$, specified in the package 
    doesn’t match the publisher name, My App, that’s associated with the developer account.
```

Its look like my AppxManifest.xml file generated at every build process places '$username$' at publisher Display Name.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: It means exactly what it says.   You have a publisher name "My App" registered with your developer account, but the publisher name associated with the package you are trying to upload is $username$.   If you right click your project in visual Studio you should see the option Store.  When you expand that choose Associate App with the Store.  You will sign in with your developer account, and choose the app you want to associate it with.  That should get everything lined up correctly.

Comment: I have already followed all this process.Still no luck

Comment: ts look like my AppxManifest.xml file generated at every build process places '$username$' at publisher Display Name.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to fix that so it puts the correct value there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native project to create app package for Windows store. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462133/appxmanifest-file-not-being-generated-correctly) on using windows native project to create store package. You can also try [Visual Studio 2015 CTP6](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs) which has a fix for this issue.