# validation error during uploading of cordova package for certification

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I want to publish my windows cordova app on app store but the problem is that after creating successfully package when I upload it on store so it show error validation error we cant read the `.appxupload`. After rebuild solution of my project visual studio auto create in manifest file

> 1)package name like (33453Techizertechsolution.TazlocCares)
>
> 2)Package display name: TazlocCares
>
> 3)after creating my package it create with name of **CordovaApp.Phone_1.1.0.5_AnyCPU_bundle.appxupload**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in VS 2015 RC but you can work around it in the VS 2013 CTP version you have by using the native project to create the appx package.  See detailed instructions in the Answer to this earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462133/appxmanifest-file-not-being-generated-correctly).

Comment: yep you write but problem is with me that my system does not support vs 2015 RC .